# How to hide view source code from yard documentation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, yard, yardoc

Iam using yard for documentation in my project but i don't want to show my source source to the users. Is there a way to hide source code in yard.

Comment: You realize that your code is totally available to the users when they use it. They can just open it and read. So what's the point in hiding this in the documentation, besides irritating the users?

Comment: it is not a open source project, it just a document for api so users(developers) can understand what are request parameters and response.

Comment: We're using rspec_api_documentation for this purpose.

Comment: ya it is preety cool i will go into it, but if i know how to hide source code in yard it would be much better

Comment: Did you find a solution? We also need to hide the source - as it's not something our API users need to see. (Nor can we allow it - proprietary source.) Our API is defined in C so no-one would otherwise be able to inspect it.

Comment: @thomthom  Didn't find any solution for yard, but https://github.com/richhollis/swagger-docs was cool, u can try it once.

Answer (score 1):

From the [YARD mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/yardoc/-HH48h-aifs):

> [my_templates/default/method_details/setup.rb]
>
> ```
> def source
>   return
> end
> ```
>
> […]
>
> Then run with 'yard -p my_templates'